# Using multiple templates in Foundation for Apps

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation-apps

I am currently working on `developing an web application` and look for a solution to `create multiple templates` in Foundation for Apps, say for example a `login screen like Pinterest(without header, footer)` and `after login` I have to load a `new template with header and footer`.  Like which I will have to create more templates based on users action, that loads all necessary files. I have a good background in `html`,`css` and `jQuery`. Browsed through some resources and couldn't find a solution to achieve this. It would be great if someone can help me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: wat is your platform?

Comment: create `header`, `footer` and other template separately. add the template in the required page, by routing those. look here, bro http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Views.html

Comment: found anything interesting, let me know. please

Comment: refer the above page. They explained it clearly boss..